# How can I infer Typescript argument types for a single implementation with overloaded signatures?

Tags: typescript, overloading

I have two signatures for my `call` method, and a single implementation:

```
call<T extends CallChannel, TArgs extends CallParameters[T]>(channel: T, ...args: TArgs): ReturnType<CallListener<T>>;
call<T extends SharedChannel, TArgs extends SharedParameters[T]>(channel: T, ...args: TArgs): ReturnType<SharedListener<T>>;
call(channel, ...args) { ... }
```

However Typescript won't typecheck because the arguments to `call` are implicitly typed `any`. Obviously they shouldn't be, they must be either `CallChannel` or `SharedChannel` type for the first argument, and similarly the second argument is one of two specific types.

But I can't define the implementation like this:

```
call<T extends CallChannel | SharedChannel, TArgs extends CallParameters[T] | SharedParameters[T]> (channel: T, ...args: TArgs) {
```

because the type `CallParameters[T]` can't resolve when `T` is a `SharedChannel` (and vice versa).

I have already provided all of the type information necessary to define `call`, how can I make typescript happy with the signature of the implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with conditional types.

Define a conditional type for args and for the return.

```
    type Args<T extends CallChannel | SharedChannel> = 
        T extends CallChannel 
        ? CallParameters[T] 
        : T extends SharedChannel 
        ? SharedParameters[T] 
        : never
```

Then update the function to use it:

```
 TArgs extends Args<T>
```

Return can use the same principle.